# Does the current inside a capacitor with dielectric becomes zero, if a DC (constant)voltage is applied?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, capacitance, dielectric

Imagine a capacitor with dielectric with conductivity $\sigma$ and constant voltage source with voltage applied say $V$ is applied to it's ends, now using Ohm's Law we have $ \vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$.

We know that as time increases, the charge on capacitor plates will increase, and thus so will $\vec{E}$, this means $\vec{J}$ should increase too. Even after we reach steady state, there should be finite $\vec{J}$ inside the dielectric.

But this seems wrong to me, as it seems to imply that there is a finite current density inside capacitor even in steady state and is not related to change in electric field. This means there is an increasing $\vec{B}$ field inside capacitor in steady state but this should be zero

So where have I gone wrong here? Is the current too minute so that it can be ignored? or is there something else?

Answer (score 4):

Dielectrics have very low conductivity, so in many applications you can ignore the current flow through it

You can model the real behaviour of an imperfect capacitor as an ideal capacitor ($I=C\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}$) in parallel with a resistor, so in total $I=C\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}+\frac{V}{R}$. The resistance will typically be really high, depending a little on the type of capacitor. Roughly, $R=100/C$ seems common for electrolytic capacitors from googling a few datasheets, so $100k\Omega$ for a $1000\mu F$ capacitor. This resistance isn't really constant and changes with temperature

It's this non-infinite resistance that makes capacitors slowly lose charge if they're not connected to anything